# Context: RuleRunning Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ThisRule.Main() at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly

Tags: autodesk-forge

Below are the exception getting in Design Automation

`12/07/2023 12:50:57]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : iLogic error`

`12/07/2023 12:50:57]  Context: RuleRunning`

`12/07/2023 12:50:57]  Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

`12/07/2023 12:50:57]    at ThisRule.Main() [12/07/2023 12:50:57]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly(Assembly assem)`

`12/07/2023 12:50:57]    at iLogic.RuleEvalContainer.ExecRuleEval(String execRule)`

`12/07/2023 12:50:57]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : End of iLogic diagnostics...`

`12/07/2023 12:50:57]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Deactivating plug-in: UpdateParamPlugin`

`12/07/2023 12:50:57]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : UpdateParamPlugin: deactivating...`

`12/07/2023 12:50:57] CoreConsole Dispose start [12/07/2023 12:50:57] CoreConsole ReleaseAll start`

`12/07/2023 12:50:58] CoreConsole ReleaseAll end [12/07/2023 12:50:58] CoreConsole Dispose end`

`12/07/2023 12:50:58] Processing failed`

`12/07/2023 12:50:58] CoreConsole exiting (-1)`

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of that error is that the rule is using `ThisApplication` which is not available inside **Inventor Server** that is also used by **Design Automation**: 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/prepare-ilogic-rules-design-automation